# How to resize plot in Matplotlib or fix the date axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Just out of curiosity,

I have plot all of my data `%matplotlib qt` for the easiness of editing the figure size. But, with the intention to open the code on Git for basic users or early learners I've been trying to plot with the simple `plt.savefig()`but the size of the figure is awful –the text doesn't even fit.

How can I easily resize the plot in order to fit all the text in the figure? Or, how can I fix the date axis?

Here is the raw code I have that show the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariorz/covid19-mx-time-series/master/data/covid19_confirmed_mx.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
df = df.loc['Colima','18-03-2020':'26-06-2020']
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%Y')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.Colima)
ax.set_xlabel('Días desde el primer caso positivo en Colima (18 de marzo, 2020)', fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('Casos positivos', fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Casos positivos acumulados de COVID-19 en Colima (26 de junio, 2020)', fontsize=10)
#plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('casos_acumulados.png', dpi=400)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is try adding

```
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
```